# How to package a Bash program for installation in Linux

Tags: bash, software-installation, packaging

I have a program written completely in Bash, which includes the main script, a set of modules called by the main script, a config file, a lib file, etc.

Since nothing needs to be compiled, what's the best way to create an installation file that places all the files in their proper locations (main script in /usr/bin/, conf file in /etc/, lib file in /usr/lib/, etc.)? Should I just use a makefile, even though no compilation is needed?

Note that I do not want to package the file. I just want to be able to pull from the repo and install from source.

Comment: You may wish to check this out. https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/12/15/howto-build-debian-package-containing-simple-shell-scripts/ Hope this helps.

Comment: You've basically ruled out the "right" answer by stating you don't want to package the file in a dpkg.  You've written your script in bash, why not write another bash script to install it, that way your target system doesn't need make installed.